# Lack of Articles in Headlines

Tags: zero-article, headlinese

Are there any rules as to an article before a noun in the singular in headlines please, i.e. lack of an article?

> Description of Type of Investment

Answer (score 3):

Articles in headlines are *optional*. The style is called as ***Headlinese***.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) quotes under the section 'Syntax'

> *Articles are usually omitted.*

It's for the sake of brevity.

A document specifically written on 'article drop' in headlines is here [(PDF, downloadable, safe).](http://users.ugent.be/~aweir/Weir-2009-headlinese.pdf)